# Site does not load homepage via ip address url | Code Igniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Domain has expired and we wish to change it to another in the future but for the time being i want to work on the site before we do the switch and want to access the site to load via temporary url: http://164.160.91.13/~southaf2/ however when accessing the url I get the get "404 Page Not Found error.

I have created info.php file and located document root so its not a server issue, tried changing base url, checked route,  checked .htaccess, checked database details, cleared cache, renamed frontend_module.php to Frontend_module.php and still get "404 Page Not Found error. 
The page you requested was not found". Please can someone help me and show me what I am doing wrong? I have searched solutions but nothing I have done has resolved my issue. Thank you

my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# here is an ability to set additional "parent" theme, images from this theme will be checked in the first order
# if they aren't existed in original theme, then in default theme
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/themes/default/(.*)
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/themes/PARENT_THEME/$2 -f
#RewriteRule ^themes/([^/]+)/(.*)$ themes/PARENT_THEME/$2

# When images from 'themes/' subfolders can not be found - look for them in default theme
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^themes/([^/]+)/(.*)$ themes/default/$2 [L]


# Combine js static files in one big file + gzip it (if possible)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*\.js) combine.php?type=javascript&files=$1


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php [L]
```

my config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://164.160.91.13/~southaf2/";
$config['subdirectory'] = "";
```

my route.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "frontend";
$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";
```

Comment: Do you have a vhost config setup on your server? It is probably set to match the domain name if you do. A quick fix is to set an entry in your `hosts` file on your local machine to point the original domain name at the IP address.

Comment: This `$config['base_url'] = "http://164.160.91.13/~southaf2/";`is a problem. Not sure if it's THE problem, but it's certainly A problem... The `base_url` parameter is expected to be just a FQDN or an IP address... no additional path